# AWS Beanstalk - can't create environment in VPC without load balancer from CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I would like to create a simple single-instance environment with AWS Elastic Beanstalk. I am able to do this from the AWS Console, but when I try to do it from the CLI, it will create a load balancer for me - seemingly regardless of what I put in my option_settings.

Here is the config file I've placed in my .ebextensions folder:

```
{
  "option_settings": [
    {
      "namespace": "aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration",
      "option_name": "InstanceType",
      "value": "t2.micro"
    },
    {
      "namespace": "aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment",
      "option_name": "EnvironmentType",
      "value": "SingleInstance"
    },
    {
      "namespace": "aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration",
      "option_name": "SecurityGroups",
      "value": "sg-XXXXXXX"
    },
    {
      "namespace": "aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration",
      "option_name": "EC2KeyName",
      "value": "XXXXXXXX"
    },
    {
      "namespace": "aws:ec2:vpc",
      "option_name": "VPCId",
      "value": "vpc-XXXXXX"
    },
    {
      "namespace": "aws:ec2:vpc",
      "option_name": "Subnets",
      "value": "subnet-XXXXXXX"
    },
    {
      "namespace": "aws:autoscaling:asg",
      "option_name": "MinSize",
      "value": 1
    },
    {
      "namespace": "aws:autoscaling:asg",
      "option_name": "MaxSize",
      "value": 1
    }
  ],
  "packages": {
    "yum": {
      "postgresql94-devel": [],
      "git": []
    }
  }
}
```

I see the load balancer listed in the "Network Tier" section of my EB environment configuration dashboard, and I've verified that it was created in the EC2 section of the AWS console.

How can I launch a Beanstalk environment from the CLI without a load balancer? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Which CLI are you using [aws cli](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/) or [eb cli](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3.html)? I am guessing eb cli.

At least the eb cli and AWS Management Console will pass some option settings by default in the API parameters in addition to the option settings you specify in your ebextensions. In the web console you get a dropdown to select a load balanced or single instance environment. In the EB CLI I think you get a prompt to select a load balanced environment. You can also pass `--single` option to `eb create`. If you don't specify anything it assumes the default which is load balanced. So even though you specified the option setting in the ebextension there is an option setting being passed in the API parameter. Elastic Beanstalk gives preference to the value set using the API over the value in ebextension.

As [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options.html#configuration-options-recommendedvalues) documentation says:

> The EB command line interface (CLI) and Elastic Beanstalk console provide recommended values for some configuration options. These values can be different from the default values and are set at the API level when your environment is created. Recommended values allow Elastic Beanstalk to improve the default environment configuration without making backwards incompatible changes to the API.
>   For example, both the EB CLI and Elastic Beanstalk console set the configuration option for EC2 instance type (InstanceType in the aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration namespace). Each client provides a different way of overriding the default setting. In the console you can choose a different instance type from a drop down menu on the Configuration Details page of the Create New Environment wizard. With the EB CLI, you can use the --instance_type parameter for eb create.

Comment: In my .ebextensions/options.config file I set the instance type and VPC id etc., but when I do a eb create it doesn't use these settings.   why is that?

Comment: Can you double check you did git add for these files?

Comment: "but when I do a eb create it doesn't use these settings. why is that?" because of options precedence. You can read more at - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options.html#configuration-options-precedence